# Find referenced value of multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `Setpoints` which contains 3 columns `Base`,`Effective` and `Actual` which contains an `id` that refers to the item found in `io`.

I would like to make a query that will return the `io_value` found in the `io` table for the `id` found in `Setpoints`.

Currently my query will return multiple `id`'s and then I query the `io` table to find the `io_value` for each `id`.

Ex Query returning the ID's in the row

```
row #   |  base  | effective  | actual
  1     |  24    |   30       | 40
  2     |  25    |   31       | 41
  3     |  26    |   32       | 42
```

But i want it return the value instead of the id

Ex returning the value for the id's instead

```
row #   |  base  | effective  | actual
  1     |  2.3   |   4.5      |  3.44
  2     |  4.2   |   7.7      |  4.41
  3     |  3.9   |   8.12     |  5.42
```

Here are the table fields

```
IO
io_value
io_id

Setpoints
stpt_base
stpt_effective
stpt_actual
```

Using postgres 9.5

What Im using now

```
SELECT * from setpoints
For each row
     SELECT io_id, io_value
     from io
     where io_id in
     (stpt_effective, stpt_actual, stpt_base); 
     // these are from previous query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by joining the `io` table three times to the `setpoints` table, using the three columns in each individual `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.io_value AS base,
       b.io_value AS effective,
       c.io_value AS actual
FROM setpoints s
JOIN io a ON a.io_id = s.stpt_base
JOIN io b ON b.io_id = s.stpt_effective
JOIN io c ON c.io_id = s.stpt_actual;
```